# Difference between string values and string literals

Tags: go

According to this golang blog post (https://blog.golang.org/strings) on strings, there is a line that states "...**string values** can contain arbitrary bytes; as we showed in this one, **string literals** always contain UTF-8 text as long as they have no byte-level escapes."

What's the difference?

Comment: String literals are part of source code files, which are always UTF8.

Comment: @zerkms you should post as an answer

Comment: @zerkms "string literals always contain UTF-8 text" means they are emitted by the compiler as string values with the text encoded with UTF-8. It has nothing to do with the encoding of the source files (which, yes, is UTF-8). The string literal could be "\u20ac" and the compiler would interpret it and emit it with UTF-8. `len("\u20ac")==3`

Comment: @TomBlodget what UTF-8 would be emitted for `"\xf0"` string literal, given `0xF0` is not a valid UTF-8 sequence? I see that the first and the only byte there is `240` https://play.golang.org/p/7f9gKHpLlRw. How does it comply with what you said "as string values with the text encoded with UTF-8"?

Comment: @zerkms You have to take in the whole description from the Go documentation, as quoted in the question.

Comment: @TomBlodget yes, now I see where I was wrong, thank you.

Answer (score 9):

This distinction rests on the definitions in the [Go language specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec) of a string *literal* and a string *value*:

> **String literal**: A string literal represents a [string constant](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants) obtained from concatenating a sequence of characters.
>
> **String value**: A string value is a (possibly empty) sequence of bytes.

and the requirement that source code is represented in source files encoded as UTF-8 text:

> **Source code representation**: Source code is Unicode text encoded in UTF-8.

Most crucially, note that a string literal is defined to be a constant, so its value is defined entirely at compile time.

---

Consider the set of valid Go source files to be those files which adhere to the language spec. By definition, such source files must be encoded using valid UTF-8. As a string literal's value is known at compile time from the contents of the source files, we see by construction that any string literal must contain valid UTF-8 text.

If we ignore byte-level escape sequences, we can see further that the compiled output of the string literal in the resulting binary must also contain valid UTF-8, as it is compiled from a UTF-8 value in the source file.

---

## Sequences of bytes? A generalisation

However, string **values** are [defined](https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_types) to be sequences of bytes,<sup>1</sup> so there is no requirement that they themselves contain valid UTF-8. Such non-UTF-8 text may arise from values received by the program from inputs other than string literals defined at compile time, such as data received over sockets or local pipes, read from a file, or string literals which contain byte-level escape sequences.

<sup>1</sup><sub>As the blog post says, this sequence of bytes may be considered to be a byte slice (`[]byte`) for most purposes. However, this is not strictly correct as the underlying implementation does not use a slice; strings are immutable and do not require to separately track their capacity. Calling `cap(str)` where `str` is of type `string` [is an error](https://play.golang.org/p/dl4om__0ZZO).</sub>

## Byte-level escape sequences

Byte-level escape sequences provide a mechanism for encoding non-UTF-8 values using a UTF-8 representation. Such sequences allow arbitrary bytes to be represented in a UTF-8 format to produce valid Go source files and satisfy the language spec.

For example, the byte sequence `b2 bd` (where bytes are here represented as space-delimited two-digit hexadecimal numbers) is [not valid UTF-8](https://play.golang.org/p/mMzGgGcaWbA). Attempting to decode this byte sequence using a UTF-8 decoder will produce an error:

```golang
var seq = "\xb2\xbd"
fmt.Println("Is 'seq' valid UTF-8 text?", utf8.Valid([]byte(seq)))
```

```
$ go run ./main.go
Is 'seq' valid UTF-8 text? false
```

Consequently, while such a byte sequence can be stored in a string in Go, it is not possible to express directly in a Go source file. Any source file which does so is invalid Go and the lexer will reject it (see below).

A backslash-escape sequence provides a mechanism for decomposing this byte string into a valid UTF-8 representation which satisfies the toolchain. The interpreted Go string literal `"\xb2\xbd"` represents the string using a sequence of ASCII characters, which can be expressed in UTF-8. When compiled, this sequence is parsed to produce a string in the compiled output containing the byte sequence `b2 bd`.

---

## Example

I'll provide a working example to demonstrate this more concretely. As we will be generating invalid source files, I cannot readily use the Go playground for this; I used the go toolchain on my machine. The toolchain is `go version go1.11 darwin/amd64`.

Consider the following simple Go program where values may be specified for the string `myStr`. For convenience, we replace the whitespace (the byte sequence `20 20 20` after the string `my value:`) with the desired bytes. This allows us to easily find the compiled output when disassembling binaries later.

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    myStr := "my value:   "
    fmt.Println(myStr)
}
```

I used a hex editor to insert the invalid UTF-8 byte sequence `b2 bd` into the final bytes of the whitespace in `myStr`. Representation below; other lines elided for brevity:

```
00000030: 203a 3d20 22b2 bd20 220a 0966 6d74 2e50   := ".. "..fmt.P
```

Attempting to build this file results in the error:

```
$ go build ./test.go
# command-line-arguments
./test.go:6:12: invalid UTF-8 encoding
```

If we open the file in an editor, it interprets the bytes in its own way (likely to be platform-specific) and, on save, emits valid UTF-8. On this OS X-based system, using `vim`, the sequence is interpreted as Unicode U+00B2 U+00BD, or `²½`. This satisfies the compiler, but the source file and hence compiled binary now contains a different byte sequence than the one originally intended. The code dump below exhibits the sequence `c2 b2 c2 bd`, as does a hex dump of the source file. (See the final two bytes of line 1 and first two bytes of line 2.)

```
$ gobjdump -s -j __TEXT.__rodata test | grep -A1 "my value"                                                                                         
 10c4c50 63746f72 796d7920 76616c75 653ac2b2  ctorymy value:..
 10c4c60 c2bd206e 696c2065 6c656d20 74797065  .. nil elem type
```

To recover the original byte sequence, we can change the string definition thus:

```
myStr := "my value: \xb2\xbd"
```

Dumping the source file produced by the editor yields a valid UTF-8 sequence `5c 78 62 32 5c 78 62 64`, the UTF-8 encoding of the ASCII characters `\xb2\xbd`:

```
00000030: 203a 3d20 226d 7920 7661 6c75 653a 205c   := "my value: \
00000040: 7862 325c 7862 6422 0a09 666d 742e 5072  xb2\xbd"..fmt.Pr
```

Yet the binary produced by building this source file demonstrates the compiler has transformed this string literal to contain the desired `b2 bd` sequence (final two bytes of the fourth column):

```
10c48b0 6d792076 616c7565 3a20b2bd 6e6f7420  my value: ..not
```

Answer (score -5):

In general, there is no difference between string value and literal. String literal is just one of ways to initialize new string variable (string as is).